# How to get nav2 BT state/running nodes

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any topic or service from where you can get the current state of the BT? How to know for example when the BT entered a recovery branch and its what iis the status of its childs?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389602/how-to-get-nav2-bt-state/running-nodes/) by [charlie92](https://answers.ros.org/users/64524/charlie92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2021-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yup! Check out the `nav2_msgs` package! We publish some behavior tree status messages regularly. The topic is subject to change but if you search for these types you can find the specific topic used in your distribution.

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/main/nav2_msgs/msg

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1